# Create symbolic links for multiple books collected from command `find`

Tags: command-line, bash

I'd like to create symbolic links for multiple books searched from running `find` command.

Firstly, I collect all the JS books

```
find ~ -type f -iregex  '.*javascript.*\.pdf' > js_books.md 2>/dev/null
```

It returns 35 books

```
../Coding/Books/HTML_Collections/Freeman E.T., Robson E. - Head First HTML5. Programming Building Web Apps with JavaScript - 2011.pdf
../Coding/Books/HTML_Collections/Learning Web Design - A Beginner's Guide to HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and Web Graphics - Jennifer Niederst Robbins - 4th Edition - August 2012.pdf
..
```

Additionally to copy them to directory js_books

```
mkdir js_books
find ~ -type f -iregex  '.*javascript.*\.pdf' -print0 -exec cp '{}' js_books
```

It works, however, multiple copies consume lots of disk space.
So I delete the books and try to make symbolic link within.

```
find ~ -type f -iregex  '.*javascript.*\.pdf' -print0 -exec ln -s '{}' js_books/'{}' \;
```

It returns nothing in dir js_books.

How to work out such a problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can loose the `-print0` primary and the strong quotes around `{}`. I suggest that you use a glob pattern instead of a regex. Something like:

```
 find ~ -type f -iname '*javascript*.pdf' -exec ln -s {} js_books \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running the command after removing the last occurrence of `'{}'` from the command-line that you entered:

`find ~ -type f -iregex  '.*javascript.*\.pdf' -print0 -exec ln -s '{}' js_books/ \;`

This should make it work.